# Pandas Multilevel Dataframe stack columns next to each other

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe in the following format:

```
id           employee    date            week      result
1234565      Max         2022-07-04      27        Project 1
                                         27.1      Customer 1
                                         27.2      100%
                                         27.3      Work
1245513      Susanne     2022-07-04      27        Project 2
                                         27.1      Customer 2
                                         27.2      100%
                                         27.3      In progress
```

What I want to achieve is the following format:

```
id           employee    date            week      result       customer      availability      status
1234565      Max         2022-07-04      27        Project 1    Customer 1    100%              Work
1245513      Susanne     2022-07-04      27        Project 2    Customer 2    100%              In progress
```

The id, employee, date and week column are index, so I have a multilevel index.

I have tried several things but nothing really brings the expected result...
So basically I want to unpivot the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this ( you need pandas version >= 1.3.0 ):

```
cols = ['result', 'customer', 'availability', 'status']
new_cols =  df.index.droplevel('week').names + cols + ['week']
df = df.groupby(df.index.names).agg(list)
weeks = df.reset_index('week').groupby(df.index.droplevel('week').names)['week'].first()
df = df.unstack().droplevel('week',axis=1).assign(week=weeks).reset_index()
df.columns = new_cols
df = df.explode(cols)
```

print(df):

```
        id employee        date     result    customer availability  \
0  1234565      Max  2022-07-04  Project 1  Customer 1         100%   
1  1245513  Susanne  2022-07-04  Project 2  Customer 2         100%   

        status  week  
0         Work  27.0  
1  In progress  27.0
```

Comment: The thing is, that I have sometimes duplicate entries as an Index. So for example, the id, employee, date and week can be the same, because they are on two projects at the same time. 
Therefore I'm getting the error:

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @Treemaster, I updated my answer. Also make sure you are on pandas version >= 1.3.0. What I did is groupby first and aggregate the 'result' values to a list and then unstack and then explode in the end.